# Instantiate an instance of a class with unknown number of attributes in Python 3

Tags: python, oop

How can I make an instance of an object (which may have many, like 20 ) attributes, without specifying default values for all attributes?

For instance, lets say I have

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, att1, att2, att3, etc....):
        self.att1 = att1
        self.att2 = att2
        self.att3 = att3
        etc
```

I can say,

```
first_thing = Thing()
first_thing.att1 = 33
```

But, if I have 30 attributes, I do not want to specify `self.att = att` for every single one.  Is there a way to get out of that? For instance, let's say that later I added an attribute and din't want to have to go back and add it to the `__init__` function, or that I did not want to declare 30 values when creating an instance of an object - is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to this?

Yes!  [Argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

For example:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.att1, self.att2, self.att3 = args
```

If it turns out you sometimes make `Thing`s with varying argument counts you can use some flow control to assign the arguments appropriately:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 3:
            self.att3 = args[2]
        if len(args) > 2:
            self.att2 = args[1]
        if len(args) > 1:
            self.att1 = args[0]
```

And sometimes [`kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) is more appropriate still:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.pitch = kwargs.get('pitch', DEFAULT_PITCH)
        self.yaw  = kwargs.get('yaw', DEFAULT_YAW)
        self.roll = kwargs.get('roll', DEFAULT_ROLL)
```

> But, if I have 30 attributes

Let's hope this is hyperbole, huh?  If you get close to that many attributes, it's probably a good time to decompose `Thing`.

Comment: It definitely was hyperbole, I just realized that setting default values for even 5 attributes gets quite long. Reading about argument unpacking makes it sound like this will work only if I have a list or tuple, I am talking about declaring no attributes at the time of instantiation and then later being able to just declare one

Answer (score 1):

You can accept variable of arguments with `*` form, like this

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    ...
```

and then, you can create new variables like this

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    for idx, item in enumerate(args):
        setattr(self, "attr{}".format(idx), item)
```

Comment: So with this format I could add any attribute after the object has instantiated even if it was instantiated with none?

Comment: @Startec When the `__init__` is invoked, the object is already created in the memory and that is passed as `self`. So, you can add any attribute, like we see above :-)

Comment: @Startec What do you mean by `instantiated with none`?

Comment: Could I for instance declare:

`my_thing = Thing():`  and then later, in some other part of the code, just say `my_thing.name = `Test'` even though the `name` attribute was never declared in the class declaration?

Comment: I like this, but could you help me understand it? Even if using `*args` instantiating the object with no arguments as in my above comment to me makes it seem like that attribute doesn't exist.  Therefore when I go to set it later, I would expect `Error: Thing has no attribute "whatever I tried to set"`

Comment: @Startec Python is very flexible. Unlike, C, C++ or JAVA, it allows you to create variables in an object, at any point of time. So, when you assign a value to an attribute, if it is already not there, it will be crated in that object.

Answer (score 0):

`namedtuple`[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or `dataclass`[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) may be what you are looking for